# C# web service - getting list of equal element names

Tags: c#, list, web-services, soap

I was creating C# SOAP web service and web method from interface specification that should have specific xml structure in request:

```
<SomeItems>
  <Value></Value>
  <Value></Value>
  ...
</SomeItems>
```

It needs to have list of elements with equal names.
When I put in C# code class like:

```
public List<int> SomeItems { get; set; }
```

I get as output (checked in SOAP UI) (epv is xmlns:epv="..."):

```
<epv:SomeItems>
  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
  <epv:int></epv:int>
</epv:SomeItems>
```

If I add another class named "Value":

```
public List<Value> SomeItems { get; set; }
public class Value
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
}
```

I get in SOAP UI:

```
<epv:SomeItems>
  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
  <epv:Value>
    <epv:Value1></epv:Value1>
  </epv:Value>
</epv:SomeItems>
```

Is there any way to get:

```
<epv:SomeItems>
  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
  <epv:Value></epv:Value>
</epv:SomeItems>
```

Where "Value" is int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> EDIT:
>   I have found solution:
>
> ```
> public SomeItems SomeItems{ get; set; }
>
> [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
> public class SomeItems
> {
>     [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
>     public List<int> Value { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> Finally in SOAP UI:
>
> ```
> <epv:SomeItems>
>   <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
>   <epv:Value>?</epv:Value>
> </epv:SomeItems>
> ```